# Linq query type equality can't figure it out

Tags: linq

I am using Linq queries in my project and i can't fix the error of anonymous types between queries. as i can't make a specific class for this i decided to convert to the same type in the query but i'm stuck with this part unable to make both parts equal

```
(from x in db.table
from d in db.table2
from c in db2.table
select new {
property = (x.property == 0) ?
((d.property == null) ? 0 :  d.property ) :
((c.property == null) ? 0 : c.property )}).distinct()
```

& in the other query

```
from x in db.table
select new
{ property = 0 }
```

all i need is a union between my queries but i can't make both parts equal
so i can use both results `var query = part1.union(part2)`

**edit :** I am not sure if me omitting to say that the properties are declared as decimal have any importance

**edit :**
found a solution where i converted the decimal to double

```
(from x in db.table
from d in db.table2
from c in db2.table
select new {
property = (x.property == 0) ?
((d.property == null) ? 0 :  d.property ) :
((c.property == null) ? 0 : c.property )}).distinct()
```

& in the other query

```
from x in db.table
select new
{ property = 0.000 }
```

& then i converted the value is 2nd part

```
(from x in db.table
    from d in db.table2
    from c in db2.table
    select new {
    property = (x.property == 0) ?
    ((d.property == null) ? 0 :  double.parse(d.property.ToString()) ) :
    ((c.property == null) ? 0 : double.parse(c.property.ToString()) )}).distinct()
```

**EDIT** 
 The issue is still persisting for some reason it's like the conversion isn't working (Anonymous error)
**Update 4.0**

```
   var query_1 = (from d in ogcc.table
                     from adh in vclt.table
                     from a in vclt.table
                     where
                         stuff
                     select new
                     {
                         tx_int = "0" //the that keeps the anonymous error
                     }).Distinct();
    //union
    var query_2 = from d in prtf.table
                    from c in prtf.table
                    from a in vclt.table.Where(a => (c.num_credit == a.no_dos_adh || c.ref_cred == a.no_dos_adh)) //left join
                    where
                        stuff
                    select new
                    {
                        tx_int = prtf.Stored_Procedure(c.num_credit).ToString(),
                    };
```

**Update + Simplifed query code** 
Only one of these keeps the error & i can't fix it 
it's tx_int i tried to convert both of these to string but the error still persists

Comment: Your core doesn't compile. It's not a proper anonymous type declaration, you're missing `new` and braces.

Comment: i shorted the query it's too long

Comment: *I can't make both parts equal*. That doesn't explain much. What error do you get?

Comment: when i use a union it throws the anonymous error thing

Comment: @TheNewGuy: I notice that you updated your question, but the updated code is obviously not the code you're really using. We can't help you very easily if you don't provide code that replicates the issue. I recommend putting explicit casts in places where you think you know what type things are until one of them complains.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior i converted everything to be the same type but i get the anonymous error on 1 property or maybe it's the hole thing i will post the 2 queries as you asked & if you want me to post the types just say it

Comment: @TheNewGuy: Same problem I described before. Clearly your code does not say `where stuff`, right? Try [reducing your actual code to the smallest example that shows the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you're seeing. Then post that code, along with all the information about the error that you're getting at that point.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're checking, e.g., `d.property == null`, I'm assuming that `d` is a `Nullable<>`, so you want to use its `.Value` property so you're using `int` instead of `int?`.

```
select new {
property = (x.property == 0) ?
((d.property == null) ? 0 :  d.property.Value ) :
((c.property == null) ? 0 : c.property.Value )}
```

Comment: i tried that but the union still doesn't work any other idea?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Or `d.property ?? 0` etc.

Comment: @TheNewGuy: It's called a "Null Coalescing Operator". It says, "Use the thing before me, unless it's null, in which case use the thing after me." `var a = b ?? c;` is the same as `var a = b != null ? b : c;`